# akka-http extractScheme return 'http' on https request

Tags: https, akka-http

I run an akka-http secured following the manual http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/server-side-https-support.html.

```
Http().bindAndHandle(
    extractScheme(s => complete(s)), 
    interface, port, 
    connectionContext = https)
```

A browser shows that https connection is ok.

The problem is that the extractScheme directive returns 'http', but expected 'https'.

Any suggestion?